# Magento2: Use one media folder for multiple instances of magento?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I want to ask a planning/architecture question, if any of you can offer a pice of advice or direct in the proper direction I’ll be grateful.

We’re having around 40 stores and another 30 stores in pipe (different languages, countries, brands - load of variations so we ended up with this big number).  All the 40 stores are in one Magento instance but with each store created - it means the database increases with a couple millions new records and is getting slower and slower. So we decided to separate them in a 3-4 instances with maximum 20 stores per instance.

All good till here, but the issue we have is the media. Our media is 120GB and still growing. If we have multiple instances that means - duplication of media and as in the past happened it will not get maintained. We could share the media folders between all the magento instances but the cache is an issue  `/media/catalog/product/cache/922ae647ccf964c3377c45a2a61b54e3/`
each instance will have a different path in url.

I had my hopes up with 2.4 feature: external media storage; which was done to incorporate the adobe stock. But unfortunately don’t think it can be applied to my case (if i didn’t misunderstood).

So, i’m asking for an advice on how I can tackle this problem.

I have to mention that we're already using a separated CDN domain and the media is heavily cached.

Thank you.

Comment: Check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage-aws-s3.html

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage.html#remote-storage-options

Comment: The issue is the cached path. I can't use same images in 2 instances of Magento, can I?

Answer (score 1):

> The Remote Storage module provides the option to store media files and
> schedule imports/exports in a persistent, remote storage container
> using a storage service, such as AWS S3. By default, Magento stores
> media files in the same filesystem that contains the application. **This
> is inefficient for complex, multi-server configurations, and can
> result in degraded performance when sharing resources**. With the Remote
> Storage module, you can store media files in the pub/media directory
> and import/export files in the var directory of the remote object
> storage to take advantage of server-side image resizing.

[image]

Reference: [Remote storage](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage.html#remote-storage-options), [AWS S3](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage-aws-s3.html)